# Insert new record problem with aspxgridview

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have two db tables like this :

```
 Product :
      Product_id int,
      ProductName varchar(200)



 Pocket :
      Pocket_id int,
      RefProduct_id int
```

As you can see, they have a related by product_id. I show a product's pocket(s) in an aspx page with aspxgridview. This gridview's datasource is an ObjectDataSource and it has insert, select and update methods. If I want to see pocket list of a product which has any pocket, there is no problem. I can insert a new pocket and I can update pocket(s) and also I can see all pocket(s) in pockets aspxgridview. But if a product hasn't got a pocket and when I want to add a pocket to this product, all areas are not enabled in pockets aspxgridview.

Do you have any suggestions for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return type of the function which returns product's pocket(s) was IQueryable but the ObjectDataSource's dataObjectTypeName is *pocket*. I changed my manager's code to returns *List* and it resolved.